# check smtp connection is working or not using PHP Mailer and get status receipt OK

Tags: php, phpmailer

I want to check whether the SMTP Server is working or not by sending mail or pinging server and get response **Receipt OK**.

i want to check whether my smtp is down or up using php . I tried to test it using below PHPmailer code. Which is the best method to test whether smtp running using php script.

```html
/**
* Simple example script using PHPMailer with exceptions enabled
* @package phpmailer
* @version $Id$
*/
 
require ('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
 
try {
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true); //New instance, with exceptions enabled
 
        $body             = "Please return read receipt to me.";
        $body             = preg_replace('/\\\\/','', $body); //Strip backslashes
 
        $mail->IsSMTP();                           // tell the class to use SMTP
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Port       = 465;                    // set the SMTP server port
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
        $mail->Username   = "bhakuq@gmail.com";     // SMTP server username
        $mail->Password   = "bhakuxxx";            // SMTP server password
 
        $mail->IsSendmail();  // tell the class to use Sendmail
 
        $mail->AddReplyTo("bhakuq@gmail.com","Riya Patel");
 
        $mail->From       = "bhakuq@gmail.com";
        $mail->FromName   = "Riya Patel";
 
        $to = "bhakuq@gmail.com";
 
        $mail->AddAddress($to);
 
        $mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message[Test Read Receipt]";
 
        $mail->ConfirmReadingTo = "someone@something.com"; //this is the command to request for read receipt. The read receipt email will send to the email address.
 
        $mail->AltBody    = "Please return read receipt to me."; // optional, comment out and test
        $mail->WordWrap   = 80; // set word wrap
 
        $mail->MsgHTML($body);
 
        $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
 
        $mail->Send();
        echo 'Message has been sent.';
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        echo $e->errorMessage();
}
```

I tried above code but still no use.

Comment: have you put the `<?php` tag before start of  the script?

Comment: My Prblm is i want to check whether SMTP server is working or not by getting response "Receipt OK"

Comment: so what error are you getting?

Comment: I m not getting error I jst want to check whether SMTP server is working or not.

Comment: are you getting emails with above script? if yes then the smtp server is working right? if you are not then it must fire some error message.

Comment: do u have any script to check whether smtp is working or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136310/discussion-between-prakash-tank-and-riya-patel).

Comment: You could of course try reading the examples provided with PHPMailer, such as [this one](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp_check.phps) that does exactly what you're asking. I can also see that you're using a *very* old version of PHPMailer and have based your code on a obsolete example, so make sure you update.